# Creating a PHP array from the contents of a file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php file that contains text in the following format.

```
line 1 -   "Title","URL","imgURL","tags"
line 2 -   "Title","URL","imgURL","tags"
line 3 -   "Title","URL","imgURL","tags"
```

It is basically structured like a database so each line is a record and 1st set of "" is always a title. 2nd set of "" is always a URL, etc.... line by line.

I'm not an experienced programmer by any stretch of the imagination. What is the best way to create an array from the contents of the file?

I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
$content = array(file_get_contents("path/content.php"));
```

I believe I need to update the structure of the data and the method I use to create the array, but I'm not sure how. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I want to be able to retrieve title, URL, imgURL, or tags from any line of text, but I don't know how to express that in an array format.

I think I want to be able to request `$content[0][1]` to get the URL from line1 and `$content[1][3]` to get the tags from line2.

Comment: what is expected outcome you want as an array.Please show that too in your answer

Comment: Please show us an expected outcome. it's hard to understand with statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = fopen("path/content.php", "r");
while($content[] = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ","));
```

You should then be able to access each element as you specified:

```
echo $content[0][1]; // echos first line, url
```

Comment: thank you! Your solution worked perfectly. I'd like to understand it better. What does the 1000 represent in the `fgetcsv($file, 1000, ","))`?

Comment: The 1000 is the max length of a single line, it is optional, but including it improves the speed of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your file is called CSV (comma separated values). Using PHP, you can parse a CSV file using the function `fgetcsv`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
/**
 * Decodes a full CSV file to an array.
 *
 * @param string $file File to decode
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 *
 * @return array[]
 */
function csv_decode($file) {
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');

    if($fh === false)
    {
        // FIXME: You should replace this with your own exception!
        throw new \Exception("Failed to open file '$file' for reading");
    }

    $rows = [];
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fh))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

The format you have encountered is known as [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (which stands for comma-separated values)

The above function decodes your data to an array with the structure you've described as can be seen from the output of the following snippet when run on your example data:

```
print_r(csv_decode('values.txt'));
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => URL
            [2] => imgURL
            [3] => tags
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => URL
            [2] => imgURL
            [3] => tags
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title
            [1] => URL
            [2] => imgURL
            [3] => tags
        )

)
```